# How to search and delete chars and then insert

Tags: vim

My string is:

```
P12106003;test_01_01
```

I am using command

```
:g/test_.._../norm 10Xi<<Esc>A>
```

Result must look like

```
<test_01_01>
```

not working.

Comment: So you want to remove the `P121...;` part and wrap the rest in `<...>`, right? Is this part of a bigger file? Can there be more text on the line?

Comment: yes, you are right. entire line looks like: *ELEMENT, TYPE=S4RS, ELSET=P12106003;test_01_01

Comment: How about `%s/\v\w\d+;(test\w+)/<\1>`

Comment: @ Lieven Keersmaekers: works well...thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X` deletes backwards. While `:norm` would enter normal mode at the start of each matching line. So you'd want `x` instead

```
g/test_.._../norm 10xi<^[A>
```

(where `^[` is a real ESC character entered with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Or you could do:

```
g/test_.._../norm dni<^[A>
```

Here, it may be simpler to use `:s`:

```
:%s/\v.*(test_.._..)/<\1>/
```

Or to delete 10 characters before each occurrence of `test_.._..` (and wrap in `<...>`):

```
:%s/\v.{10}(test_.._..)/<\1>/g
```

Or anything that matches `P<digits>;`:

```
:%s/\vP\d+;(test_.._..)/<\1>/g
```

Comment: :%s/\v.{10}(test_.._..)/<\1>/g    and :%s/\vP\d+;(test_.._..)/<\1>/g are works well for me....thank you